# Is there a way to Rate Limit Sent Emails in Play Framework?

Tags: email, playframework-1.x, amazon-ses

How can I implement a RateLimit for sending emails via play.mvc.Mailer?

I'm implementing SES for my play framework 1.2.5 application to replace GMAIL. The application runs into situations where it may send out 200 emails at a time (notifications) so I need to RateLimit them to 5 recipients/second. Amazon recommends Google Guava's RateLimit class (http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxKR75VKOYDS60/How-to-handle-a-quot-Throttling-Maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-quot-error). I'm currently extending Play's Mailer class. If I try to call my own send method such as sendWithRateLimit(Object...args) I lose the contexts which were acquired using play's LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer class so it doesn't know which template to invoke.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Being as though Play is stateless/scalable, I am second thinking my RateLimit approach, I may create an email server which handles all emails and takes care of the rate limiting, I will post my solution when it is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down this road for about 6 hours and realized that I was writing way too much code in order to utilize SES. We're going to utilize Mandrill's Heroku add-on instead: https://addons.heroku.com/mandrill

Answer (score 1):

Too late now, but the way to do this would have been to:

1. create a model that represents your emails, lets call it `Email`, save them to the DB
2. create a job that fetches the next X `Email` records, and is scheduled to run at the rate allowed
3. for each `Email` record, send an email using the mailer

Comment: Yeah I started to do that but it just wasn't worth it to me. Also, the job would have to live on it's own server as well in order to be separate from the web server in case I needed to spin up multiple instances.

Comment: it does not have to be a separate server, but you're right that you need to take care that two servers don't run the same job at the same time.  storing the job/email queue in the DB makes multiple servers/dynos possible.

Comment: The reason I would have this running in its own app (seperate server) is because otherwise I'd need to dynamically calculate the RateLimiter's duration based on how many dynos are running. For example, if I need to limit to 10 emails per second to SES, with 10 servers, they could be sending 100 emails per second.